# json.stringify convert to array php not inserting in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to insert into a database some data from a json.stringify. Particularly I do the following:

```
$('#get-checked-data').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var checkedItems = [];
    $("#check-list-box li.active").each(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
        var checkedItem = { subarea: $this.attr('data-value') };
    checkedItems.push(checkedItem);
    });

    var lawcase = JSON.stringify(checkedItems);

    $('#display-json').html("<input type='text' name='case' value='" + 

lawcase + "' readonly >");
        });
});
```

The value from the json.stringify looks like this:

[{"subarea":"1"},{"subarea":"2"}]

I pick the data and I send it through POST to the class that handles the information.

```
$user->case=$_POST['case'];
```

Then I  manipulate the data to convert the string into an array with:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO subarea (id,subarea_id,area_id) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)';



  $usercase=$this->case;
   $check=json_decode($usercase,true);
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
```

and the array looks like this, for me it seems incorrect but I am new into arrays and do not how to fix this error:

array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["subarea"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["subarea"]=> string(1) "2" } }

Finally I run the foreach to insert

```
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
 foreach($check as $key => $item)
{           
    $stmt->bindValue(':a',$this->user_id) ;
    $stmt->bindValue(':b', $item['subarea']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':c', $areavalue);//This comes from another variable, don't pay atention.
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

But I received Notice: Array to string conversion in the  $stmt->bindValue(':b', $item); line. I have tried nearly everything real_escape_string, encode, decode everything but still I am getting an unsuccessful output. I have checked stackflow and others website, the manual and I am missing something that does not let me solve the problem.

Hope someone can help me, thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** THE CODE IS CORRECT, I AM USING A SHARED SERVER AND THE PROBLEM COMES FROM THE CONFIGURATION OF THIS SERVER. THANK YOU FOR YOUR RESPONSES.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the subarea key, e.g. $item['subarea'] rather than the array itself, otherwise it'll give you the array to string conversion error.

Comment: I tried that as well and the problem is that the database receives double results. I believe the problem is in the array that I built with json_decode($usercase,true); but I don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: Could it be possible that the problem might come from ["subarea"]=> string(1) "1" . Specifically from string(1)?

Comment: I believe it's doing what's expected because you have two array elements, it's going to loop over them and execute the statement twice, once for subarea => 1 and once for subarea => 2.

Comment: The problem is that it is inserting two times one and two times 2. I  will give another try tomorrow but for me the array does not have the format and that's why I am getting strange values.

Comment: Is there another loop going on somewhere? If the value of $check is the array that you've pasted in then it should only run two times.